# How to omit columns from select mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the query below:

```
INSERT INTO kitchen (account_id, ingredient)
    SELECT
        kitchen.account_id,
        ingredients.ingredient,
        kitchen.ingredient,
        count(*) c
    FROM planned_meals
        JOIN meal
        JOIN kitchen
        JOIN ingredients
    WHERE planned_meals.mid = meal.mid
        AND ingredients.rid = meal.recipe_id
        AND ingredients.ingredient != ""
        AND ingredients.ingredient NOT LIKE CONCAT("%",kitchen.ingredient,"%")
    GROUP BY ingredients.ingredient
    HAVING c = (SELECT count(*) FROM kitchen);
```

When I run the select section individually I get:

[image]

As a result of the c column I am receiving an error because it conflicts with the number of fields in the INSERT INTO function.

How can I make the select query omit the c column in order for the INSERT INTO to work? I cannot make the number of columns the same because I need the count column in order for my HAVING function to work

Comment: Make the number of columns the same

Comment: Note that your query fails if, for instance, a recipe contains both butter and peanut butter.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying. Noted.

Comment: Your query does not make sense.  You are missing `JOIN` conditions on the `kitchen` table.  In addition, you are using `JOIN` with no `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While inserting, you have defined 2 columns `(account_id, ingredient)`, whereas you are providing 4 columns `kitchen.account_id, ingredients.ingredient, kitchen.ingredient, count(*) c`. You can just remove columns from select which you don't want to insert

```
INSERT INTO kitchen (account_id, ingredient) 
SELECT kitchen.account_id, ingredients.ingredient 
 FROM planned_meals JOIN meal JOIN kitchen JOIN ingredients WHERE planned_meals.mid = meal.mid AND ingredients.rid = meal.recipe_id AND ingredients.ingredient != "" AND ingredients.ingredient NOT LIKE CONCAT("%",kitchen.ingredient,"%") 
GROUP BY ingredients.ingredient 
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM kitchen);
```

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention that the count column is essential for the having section of my query to work and produce the correct output so I cannot remove it

Comment: Just replace ```c``` with ```count(*)```

Comment: Ok that worked, thank you. Don't know how that slipped my mind

Comment: @hope1234: Dude, just accept the answer if it works for you :-)